# What is the long version of "blocks[i][j].isColorBox() ? pieceColor : backgroundColor"?

Tags: java, c++, syntax, if-statement

I've read this line of code: `blocks[i][j].isColorBox() ? pieceColor : backgroundColor` and I'm wondering what is its `if` statement counterpart. Or if it's really an `if` statement. I'm new in programming and I'm still learning the language. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines, if you're returning the color value at the end of a method:

```
if (blocks[i][j].isColorBox()) {
    return pieceColor;
} else {
    return backGroundColor;
}
```

Or if you're assigning the color value to a variable:

```
if (blocks[i][j].isColorBox()) {
    someVariable = pieceColor;
} else {
    someVariable = backGroundColor;
}
```

Either way, the "long" version of a [conditional expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_%28programming%29#As_a_ternary_operator) (a.k.a. ternary operator of the form `?:`) would be to use an `if/else` and do something with the values. Notice that the fundamental difference between an `if/else` and a conditional expression is that the former is an statement without a *value* whereas the later is an expression which evaluates to the value of its operands.

Comment: It's interesting to note that `if/else` being a statement instead of an expression is an arbitrary design choice. For example, Scala only has Java's `?:` expression, but it's spelled `if/else` :) That is, in Scala you can say `someVariable = if (blocks[i][j].isColorBox()) pieceColor else backGroundColor`.

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of like (depending on what you are doing with the result)

```
if(blocks[i][j].isColorBox()) {
    //... pieceColor
} else {
    //... backgroundColor
}
```

e.g. if it's an assignment then

```
a = b ? c : d;
```

is like

```
if(b) {
   a = c;
} else {
   a = c;
}
```

From the specification [15.25 Conditional Operator ? :](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.25)

> The conditional operator ? : uses the boolean value of one expression to decide which of two other expressions should be evaluated.

So, `b ? c : d` is like a expression with condition for which the result of evaluation of the expression would be the result of evaluation of the second expression `c` if the result of evaluation of the first expression `b` is true, otherwise it's the result of evaluation of the thirst expression `d`.

Answer (score 1):

`?` is the [**ternary operator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a), and it is somewhat analogous to an `if`-statement. Basically,

```
bool ? a : b
```

means "if `bool` is true, then use value `a`, otherwise use value `b`". In your case:

```
blocks[i][j].isColorBox() ? pieceColor : backgroundColor
```

means "if `blocks[i][j].isColorBox()` is true, use `pieceColor`, otherwise use `backgroundColor`".

---

Therefore, the following are generally equivalent:

```
n = blocks[i][j].isColorBox() ? pieceColor : backgroundColor
```

and

```
if (blocks[i][j].isColorBox()) 
    n = pieceColor;
else 
    n = backgroundColor;
```